# How concatenate string and variable to a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I need to concatenate a string and a variable to fill another string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *te1;
    char *te2;
    char *tabela[2];

    te1 = "text 1";
    te2 = "text 2";
    tabela[0] = "text 0, " + te1 + ", " + te2;
    printf("%s\n", tabela[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

> text 0, text 1, text 2

Answer (score 2):

Ooof!  You need to read up on `C`, pointers and arrays.

Firstly, you need to allocate some space, either using `malloc` and assign to a pointer or `char buffer[200]`

Next be aware that you cannot add strings like other languages.  You need to either `strcat` or one of its variants or `sprintf(buffer, "text 0 %s, %s",te1, te2);`

There's some clues but with no ill intent meant, you really do need to ready up and understand some fundamentals.